# Does Kubernetes have the option to have a main manifest file which references all the other manifest files

Tags: kubernetes

Currently, I have a number of Kubernetes manifest files which define `service`'s or `deployment`'s. When I do an `kubectl apply` I need to include -all- the files which have changes and need to be applied.

Is there a way to have a main manifest file which references all the other files so when I do `kubectl apply` i just have to include the main manifest file and don't have to worry manually adding each file that has changed, etc.

Is this possible?

I did think of making an alias or batch file or bash file that has the `apply` command and -all- the files listed .. but curious if there's a 'kubernetes' way ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have a directory with manifests and do the following:

```
kubectl apply -R -f manifests/
```

In this case kubectl will recursively traverse the directory and apply all manifests that it finds.

Comment: what defines a 'manifest' ? any file with an `.yaml` extension? (i'm reading the docs @ https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#apply to learn more/this)

Comment: basically any file. If kubectl will find file which cannot be treated as manifest or has syntax error - it will fail.

Comment: Thank you kindly @vasilyangapov! really appreciate your help :)